# Why does this create an infinite list of negative odd numbers?

Tags: c, infinite

Why does the following instruction create an infinite list of negative numbers (-1, -3, -5, ...) if i=1?

```
while (i--)
  printf("\n%i", --i);
```

Comment: Technically it's not infinite, it'll go until you get past `INT_MIN`, then have some implementation-defined behaviour. But for your question, why wouldn't it. What would you expect it to do instead?

Comment: You should mention what the focus of your concern is. Is it the true evaluation of the while loop where you think it should be false or just why it prints negative numbers in 2 steps. You see that we already provided answers where not all focus both and just one thing only.

Comment: @ThomasJager: The C standard says the behavior on integer overflow is undefined, by which it means it does not impose any requirements. This includes the fact that it does not require an implementation to define the behavior, so the behavior is implementation-defined only if an implementation chooses to define it.

Comment: I thought that the -- operator inside the printf() would only change the value of i for printing, not the value of the variable itself (begginner here). Knowing that clarifies it all. Thank you all so much for the answers. (I apologize if maybe my English isn't flawless, it's not my native language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 1                        // 1
while (i--)                  // value of 'i--' is 1 is true; side-effect i = 0
    printf("\n%i", --i);     // print value of '--i' ie -1, side-effect i = -1
while (i--)                  // value of 'i--' is -1 is true; side-effect i = -2
    printf("\n%i", --i);     // print value of '--i' ie  -3, side-effect i = -3
while (i--)                  // value of 'i--' is -3 is true; side-effect i = -4
    printf("\n%i", --i);     // print value of '--i' ie  -5, side-effect i = -5
...
```

Note that *side-effect* above may occur before or after (or even during) the evaluation of rest of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special. You have negative number of i, which is equal to 1 at the beginning (and then -1,-3,-5,...) because you decrement variable i two times. First, you are doing it in conditional expression: "while(i--)". After it, it happens in while block of code: "printf("\n%i", --i);". Finally, it continues again and again decreasing by 2 since you are using while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `i--` is a post decrement operator. Meaning, the value of i is used in expression followed by the evaluation of the expression itself. This causes the value of i in your comparison to different from the one present in the print statement which makes the infinite loop.

1. `i--` Post decrement operation which tells that the value be used
   first followed by the expression evaluation.
2. `--i` pre decrement operation which tells that the expression be
   evaluated first followed by using the result of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` condition uses post-decrement. That means it tests the original value of `i`, which is `1`, and then decrements the value to `0`. Since `1` is truthy, it goes into the loop.

Inside the loop, you print `--i`. This is pre-decrement, so it sets `i` to `-1`, and prints that value.

On the next iteration the same thing happens. It tests `-1`, which is truthy, decrements it to `-2`, enters the loop body, decrements it to `-3`, and prints that.

Eventually your code will run into undefined behavior when `i` overflows below the smallest negative number. In most implementations it will wrap around and continue the same progression, but the actual behavior is not specific by the language.

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration, i decrements 2 times, which is making series 1, -1, -3, and so on. Always positive values which lead to an infinite loop. If you choose i=2 then series will be 2, 0 and that's all. After getting zero while the loop will get exit.

Answer (score 0):

`i` seems to be of type `int` and is with that a signed integer which also covers a negative range.

The standard mandates that an `int` needs to be capable to represent at least a range of `−32767` to `32767`.

If you decrement it, the value can go down to `INT_MIN`.

If you decrement the value after it has been reached the border of `INT_MIN`, the behavior is undefined.

`i` is decremented by `2` in each iteration, so the output shows a decrease in 2er steps.

If the loop is infinite is dependent upon how the implementation treats a decrementation after `INT_MIN`.

The `while` condition is always true as long as `i` is non-zero, which is the case here as `i` is decremented by 2 at the first iteration and there as well thereafter `i` is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Because you substract 2 from the odd number two it will never be zero on most implementations.

```
while (i--)
  if(i & 1) printf("\n%i", i);
```

will stop at some point.